# how can you scale text on Android

Tags: android

I wonder if it is possible to scale text in the x-axis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

android:textScaleX can be used for this requirement.

For more details:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3atextScaleX

Comment: thank you for the hint: this wil indeed help me to scale in the x-axis. Do you know if there is a way to set spacing between characters?